# When should I use to_representation?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I'm looking for guidance on if my usage of to_representation is a decent approach or if there is a better way to solve my specific problem.

I have this code in my serializers.py:

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import Project, Task, TaskStatus

class ProjectSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Project
        fields = ["name", "description", "start_date", "end_date", "pkid"]

    def create(self, validated_data):
        organization = validated_data.pop('organization', None)
        project = Project.objects.create(**validated_data)

        if organization:
            project.organization = organization
            project.save()

        return project


class TaskStatusSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Task
        fields = ["name", "description", "pkid"]

    def create(self, validated_data):
        task_status = TaskStatus.objects.create(**validated_data)
        return task_status
class TaskSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    project = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(queryset=Project.objects.all())
    status = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(queryset=TaskStatus.objects.all())
    class Meta:
        model = Task
        fields = ["name", "description", "project","status","pkid"]

    def create(self, validated_data):
        project = validated_data.pop('project')
        status = validated_data.pop('status')
        
        task = Task.objects.create(project=project, status=status, **validated_data)

        task.save()
        return task
    
    def to_representation(self, instance):
        representation = super().to_representation(instance)
        representation['project'] = ProjectSerializer(instance.project).data
        representation['status'] = TaskStatusSerializer(instance.status).data
        return representation
```

What I'm trying to do is have my TaskSerializer respond to an API request and provide me task, taskstatus, and project objects that I use to populate a Vue list.
Within the view list, I have a create modal that loads where the user can select the project via drop down and specify the status.  These come back to the serializer as a post where I use the project_id and status_id to create a task.

The to_representation usage here makes the process work but it feels non-standard. Is there a better more elegant way to handle my use case?

The code above is working but I'd like to know if there is a better standard Django approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [Docs](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#custom-fields) The .to_representation() method is called to convert the initial datatype into a primitive, serializable datatype.

So if you want to **override** the representation of a field or **add custom field** you can use this method.

You can also make use of **.SerializerMethodField()** that is a read_only_field:

```
class TaskSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
   project = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

   class Meta:
        model = Task
        fields = ["somefields", "project"]
    
   def get_project(self, obj):
      return ProjectSerializer(obj.project).data
```